# Add sequential number at the beginning of files

Tags: bash

I have 5 files I want to add sequential numbers and tabulation at the beginning of each file but the second file should start with the last number from the first file and so on here's an example:

```
file1
line1
line2
....
line13

file2
line1
line2


file5
line1
line2
```

Output file1

```
1  line1
........
13 line13
```

output file2

```
14 line1
15 line2
```

And so on

Comment: Sounds like homework :)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. (1) Do you have a single file as input or multiple? (2) Do you want a single file is output or multiple? (3) Should the files be updated, or have a different name?

Comment: Are the files themselves to changed, or just the output?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to concatenate files and number lines, use `cat`:

```
cat -n file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

if you want to create a separate output file for each input file, use awk:

```sh
awk '{
  printf "%d\t%s\n",NR,$0 > ("output_"FILENAME)
}' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

reads `file1..5`, numbers lines and outputs them to `output_file1..5`. note that if you have too many files then above awk command will fail with an error like *too many open file descriptors.*, in that case use following, it closes the previous file when input file changes.

```
awk '
FILENAME!=f{close("output_"f);f=FILENAME}
{printf "%d\t%s\n",NR,$0 > ("output_"f)}
' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

Comment: very nice addition of the close. (already upvoted before, can't do it again ;-))